# Spring Web Jackson ObjectMapper reference

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, jackson2, jackson-dataformat-xml

Is there a way to Autowire / Inject ObjectMapper (superclass) when the environment has both ObjectMapper bean from Jackson and XmlMapper (subclass of ObjectMapper) created for application's own purpose?

```
@Bean
public XmlMapper xmlMapper() {
  var xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
  ... deserialization features
  return xmlMapper;
}
```

Now in another class where it is used, I should be able to inject ObjectMapper (default created by Jackson) as well as XmlMapper (custom created)

```
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@Autowired
private XmlMapper xmlMapper;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can declare both in config file:

```
@Bean
public XmlMapper xmlMapper() {
    return new XmlMapper();
}

@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    return new ObjectMapper();
}
```

Comment: My use-case is to use the `ObjectMapper` as such created by Jackson. So, when I try to inject `ObjectMapper` as such, it gets injected by the `XmlMapper` (subclass) always. Is there a way to inject the base-class without `Qualifier` ?

Comment: You are right if you do not declare ObjectMapper bean in the config, then only your custom XmlMapper will be injected (autowired), but if you declare it, then these 2 different mappers can be injected even without using a qualifier.