# how to return response with body in xml format from filter in springboot?

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, filter

Unable to get the response with body in xml format from filter in springboot. I can get in JSON format correctly by using below code:

```
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
            response.reset();
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
            response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT));
            response.setContentType(request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT));
            objectMapper.writeValue(response.getWriter(), ErrorUtil.createErrorsVO(ErrorTypeEnum.HEADER_NOT_SET, INTUIT_OFFERING_ID));
```

Answer (score 1):

As I can see you're using Jackson already for serializing to JSON. I'd recommend to use the Jackson XML extension:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Please note that this only works for Spring MVC out of the box. If you wish to use the `XmlMapper`, the counterpart of the `ObjectMapper`, in Spring Security, you have to inject a bean. Problem is, that Spring doesn't register a bean of type `XmlMapper` by default.

If you just want to use XML serialization you can do the following:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public XmlMapper xmlMapper(MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter converter) {
    return (XmlMapper) converter.getObjectMapper();
}
```

After this you can inject a bean of type `XmlMapper` in your filter.

**EDIT**

I answered first and then thought/researched. There already seems to be questions that deal with the problem, take a look at them:

- [How to autowire default XmlMapper in Spring Boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28812065/how-to-autowire-default-xmlmapper-in-spring-boot-application)
- [Spring Web Jackson ObjectMapper reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72995871/spring-web-jackson-objectmapper-reference)